# How to request data from HTML form while using Symfony form for submit button

Tags: php, html, symfony, http-post, symfony-forms

I am using a hybrid of Symfony forms only for submit and cancel buttons, where any user input data is sent via HTML.

Here is my Controller Code that gets the request. It retrieves whether or not the `save` button was clicked fine but it passes in null for `$content`

```
$form = $this->createForm(FormType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label'=> 'Save changes form',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']));
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->get('save')->isClicked()){
        if ($form->isValid()){
            $content = $request->get('content');
            $announcementToCreate = new Announcement($content, $currentUser);
            $currentUser->getAnnouncements()->add($announcementToCreate);
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($announcementToCreate);
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```

Here is my twig/html code. I am using a modal for this form. I was able to get the desired results using pure html.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    {{ form(form) }}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        <textarea class="form-control" id="announcementText" rows="5" name="contents"></textarea>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to add your textarea input to the Form:

```
$form = $this->createForm(FormType::class)
    ->add('content', TextareaType::class, [
        'label' => false,
        'attr' => [
            'rows' => 5,
            'class' => 'form-control'
        ]
    ])
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
        'label'=> 'Save changes form',
        'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']
    ]);
```

2. `{{ form(form) }}` is used for a complete form render, you don't need to use it alongside with `form_start`/`form_end`.

Just do a complete form render:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

or render each part of the form individually:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

  {{ form_row(form.content) }}
  {{ form_row(form.submit) }}

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

3. You don't need to check your button for a "click", just check if your form was submitted:

```
...

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    // You can get your data directly from the form:   
    $content = $form->get('content')->getData();

    $announcementToCreate = new Announcement($content, $currentUser);
    $currentUser->getAnnouncements()->add($announcementToCreate);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($announcementToCreate);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. is there any way to achieve the results without using Symfony forms for the text input and just html? We are trying to avoid using Symfony forms except for security purposes

Comment: @d1596 Yeah, just put your textarea between `form_start` and `form_end` and get your data through the `$request` in the controller.

Or you can just use the plain `<form>` and `<submit>` tags in your code.